# Globals in symfony (like BD config)

Tags: php, symfony

How I can setup a global var in symfony? I'm developing a SaaS multitenant in Symfony and I need to create a dynamical connection in order to load the tenant information to display for the logged user.

I need to change this:

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: xxxxxxx
    database_user: xxxxxx
    database_password: xxxx
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_path: null
```

Is it possible to config this as a global dynamic var?

Answer (score 1):

In the doc, it is said that if you want to have global variables in your yaml config files, you have to surround them with '%'.

Not sure if that's what you want, but here's the link : http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html